# Merge two dictionaries with keys only from the first dict

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

I want to merge two dictionaries so that the resulting dict has keys from the first dict and values from the first and second.

```py
>>> A = {'AB': 'a', 'A': 'a'}
>>> B = {'AB': 'b', 'B': 'b'}
>>> merge_left(A, B)
{'AB': 'b', 'A': 'a'}
```

This is somewhat similar to a left outer join used in merging database tables in that one side is used as the "base" and the other side is compared to it.

Here is a table of what value each key should have in the resulting dict.

| Possible Situations | Key in A | Key not in A |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Key in B | Use B's value | **Don't include** |
| Key not in B | Use A's value | *N/A* |

Is there a function `merge_left` or something similar that returns the dict above?

Answer (score 2):

I used [`dict.get`'s ability to return a default value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to make a fairly short `merge_left` function. This uses a dict-comprehension over `key, value` pairs of the first dict and checks them against the second.

```py
def merge_left(defaults, override):
    return {key, override.get(key, default) for key, default in defaults.items()}
```

Since this function is just returning a dict-comprehension, you can "inline" it directly into your code.

```py
>>> A = {'AB': 'a', 'A': 'a'}
>>> B = {'AB': 'b', 'B': 'b'}
>>> {k: B.get(k, a) for k, a in A.items()}
{'AB': 'b', 'A': 'a'}
```